# Using on_trait_change in ipython notebook widgets

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to use the IntSlider widget in IPython.html.widgets, and I want to call a function whenever the slider value changes. Additionally, I want to pass multiple arguments into the function. I was able to use on_trait_change() to call a function but have no idea how to pass arguments:

```
def somefn(parameter1, parameter2):
   print (parameter1, parameter2)

slider = widgets.IntSlider(min=0,max=3,step=1)
slider.on_trait_change(somefn)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a partial.

```
from IPython.display import display
import ipywidgets as widgets

def somefn(parameter1,my_arg):
    print ("parameter1: {}".format(parameter1))
    print ("my_arg: {}".format(my_arg))

from functools import partial
somefn_arg_0 = partial(somefn, my_arg=0)

slider = widgets.IntSlider(min=0,max=3,step=1)
slider.observe(somefn_arg_0)
display(slider)
```

Note I have replaced the deprecated `on_trait_change` with `observe`.